# UITextFields not responding in iOS 9.0 migrated project

Tags: ios, uitextfield, freeze

I'm migrating a project from iOS 7.0/8.0 to 8.0/9.0 and I'm facing this problem :

Any `UITextField` I have on my UI freezes the app but doesn't trigger a crash.

I've tried to remove delegates, even `IBOutlet`s. I've created a new empty controller, with just one `UITextField`, that my appDelegate shows instead of any other, but nothing works...

Is anyone facing the same issue ?

Comment: When the app is frozen, what does the debugger backtrace tell you? My guess is, a misbehaving notification handler.

Answer (score 0):

Damn it, it solved itself...

My only move before that was creating a Watch Extension, which I deleted by rebasing my project on a previous commit.

Anyway it was truly stranged, I also had a crash on UIAlertController that I used nowhere in my app...

Thanks anyway !